# Can the aurora and snow be seen at Rovaniemi in October?

Tags: europe, finland, auroras, rovaniemi

If I go to Rovaniemi in October to visit the Santa Claus Village, is this a time when it is common to see the Aurora Borealis and maybe some snow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best time to visit is around Easter, when there's lots of snow, it's not too cold and there's sunlight, but October is a reasonable option.

**Snowfall**: Statistically, the "first snow" (*ensilumi*), meaning uninterrupted snow cover, falls around [the 2nd week of October](http://yle.fi/uutiset/3-6882938).  However, this is highly variable and there's a real chance of slush or rain, especially towards the beginning of the month.

**Aurora**: Statistically, October is the third best month for spotting auroras in northern Finland, behind only Jan/Feb.  (Rovaniemi is about halfway between Ivalo=I and Oulu=O in [this graph](http://ilmatieteenlaitos.fi/tiedote/1032265372).)

**Sunlight**: Days are "normal", meaning [from 9 AM to 5 PM](https://www.paivyri.fi/index.php?dt=1475614800&ref=6&id=).  (In December, you get the [polar night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_night), meaning no sun at all, for a few days.)